# Saved state exception

Tags: android

I'm getting the following exception with my app.  I believe this happens when the user leaves the app for a long time then returns to it.  I am unable to replicate it however it is showing up in my crash logs a lot.  I have no idea why this is happening so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1764)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:198)
at com.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:235)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
... 11 more
```

Line 235 is the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    // line 235
```

My onSaveInstanceState() is pretty simple:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    state.putInt("id1", id1);
    state.putInt("id2", id2);
    state.putInt("id3", id3);
    state.putInt("id4", id4);

}
```

Comment: is it because one of id1, id2, id3, id4 equates to -1 when you are saving it?

Comment: They shouldn't ever be -1, however, I dont believe the value of the int matters.

Comment: Are you sure line 235 is that line. The build you got the Log from is the same you are checking?

Comment: Yup, I triple checked. You can also see in the stacktrace that the parent onCreate() is called.

Comment: You'll need to find steps to reproduce it before you can do anything about it

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem, I believe it a bug with android. Take a look at this thread for a possible solution http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22404

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the exact same bug. The line numbers are off. Of course that could just be a different version of the support library with the same bug... or it could be a different bug.

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same problem, I followed the advice given in Kenny's link:

I used the following:

```
FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
```

This will display in the logs all the calls on the `FragmentManager` (fragments added, deleted, hidden etc.).

It allowed me to see what was wrong in my case, one of the fragments in my app was sometimes not saved properly in the instance and its content was null.

Then the crash happened with the same error log when the app tried to restore this null fragment from the instance.

In my case this fragment was a little special and created automatically. To be sure not to get the error again, I removed the fragment from the `FragmentManager` before exiting the `Activity`.

Comment: Upvote for `FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, occurring with orientation changes, but it only happened with older Android versions (4.0.4), newer versions like 4.4.2 were fine. I want to share with you how I fixed it.

As Kenny and Yoann suggested, I used

```
FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
```

and found out that too much removing has been done. I had to remove `ft.remove(df)` from my code and now it's fine with both versions mentioned above. This is my code:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    final DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
    if (df != null) {
        df.dismiss();
        // ft.remove(df);
        frag = new MyDialogFragment();
        frag.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

For the sake of completeness, this is what I have done in `onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outstate)`:

```
if (frag != null) {
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tag", frag);
}
```